# Function call on left hand side of assignment must return Variant or object

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If TextBox1 = Hayu And TextBox2 = 2007 Then

MsgBox = "login successful"

Me.Hide

Else

MsgBox = "incorrect creditanls"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to call the function `MsgBox` so remove the `=`, you cannot assign something to a function: `MsgBox "login successful"`

Comment: Have you edited both calls to `MsgBox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work better:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If TextBox1 = "Hayu" And TextBox2 = "2007" Then
        MsgBox "login successful"
        Me.Hide
    Else
        MsgBox "incorrect creditanls"
    End If
End Sub
```